# Adding columns programmatically to DataGridView takes too long

Tags: c#, datagridview, datatable

I am using C#, I am adding Columns to a `DataGridView` programmatically. number of columns is something between 30-50 columns (number of columns is because I want to show data vertically) for now I have one `DataGridView` at the page but by the time it will be up to 5 table, and all of the processes are in the page load  but it takes much time to load the page like 3 minutes for only one grid, I am adding columns like this:

```
 for(int i=0 ; i <dt.rows.count ; i++)
 {
    dgv.Columns.Add("c"+i.tostring(),"c"+i.tostring());
    dgv.Rows[0].Cells[i].Value=i+1;
    dgv.Rows[1].Cells[i].Value=dt.Rows[i].ItemArray[2].tostring();
    dgv.Rows[2].Cells[i].Value=somevalue-othervalue;
 }
```

`dt` is my `datatable` name and the values are from `datatable`, some how it takes too long but the data is not that much and the process is not that complicated so what can I do here?
should I run the process in the background and populate the `gridview` using another `datatable`? I have done this but I do not see any changes.

Comment: Why don't you add the columns to the `DataTable` and just bind the `DataGridView` to the `DataTable`?

Comment: I need to add more and more columns after page load , and i have some columns in the   `DataTable` that are not used in the `Gridview`, should i make another   `DataTable`  and design as i like?and the bind the grid view with second datatable?

Comment: So, add more and more columns after page load, then data bind to the new table.

Comment: I tried it and it is way faster! thanks in advance, i have another question why binding is way faster than generating columns?

Comment: I have no idea, but the whole idea of this (and most other) controls is to display the data they are bound to. That's the use case they are optimized for.

Comment: i have tried it to add the values cell by cell when the columns are generated and that is way faster than making columns and adding data to rows, i agree with you about the use case optimization.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67377/discussion-between-user3786134-and-john-saunders).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the extra columns to the `DataTable` ahead of time. Fill them in when you have the data.

But then bind the `DataTable` to the `DataGridView`.